# How pass variable to sqlQuery in r

Tags: sql, r

How do you pass a variable to sqlQuery in r?

```
cn = odbcConnect("Odbc")
x = "30"
data1 <- sqlQuery(cn, "SELECT Year
      ,Price
      ,WinterRain
      ,AGST
      ,HarvestRain
      ,Age
      ,FrancePop
  FROM SSIS1.dbo.wine
  WHERE Age = " x)
```

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  FROM SSIS1.dbo.wine
WHERE Age = " x"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paste0`/`sprintf` to construct the query dynamically.

```
x = "30"
query <- paste0("SELECT Year,Price,WinterRain,AGST,HarvestRain,Age,FrancePop FROM SSIS1.dbo.wine WHERE Age = ", x)
data1 <- sqlQuery(cn, query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since variables can be a string or number that may or may not require quote enclosures for literal values in SQL, consider a [parameterized solution](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and not simply concatenation of query and variable. This involves preparing an SQL statement with placeholder like qmark, `?`, followed by a subsequent step to bind parameters.

Since `RODBC` package itself does not support parameters, consider [`RODBCext`](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/RODBCext.html), the extension package which does with `sqlPrepare` and `sqlExecute` methods. Below shows a one-statement version:

```r
data <- RODBCext::sqlExecute(
                     cn, 
                     query="SELECT Year
                                  ,Price
                                  ,WinterRain
                                  ,AGST
                                  ,HarvestRain
                                  ,Age
                                  ,FrancePop
                            FROM SSIS1.dbo.wine
                            WHERE Age = ?", 
                     data=data.frame("30"), 
                     fetch=TRUE
        )
```

Currently, `RODBCext` has been [removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/index.html) as of the date of this answer. Consequently, try installing from latest archives:

```r
### LATEST VERSION (2020-02-05) FROM ARCHIVES:
###      (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RODBCext/)

package = "https://cran.r-project.org/package=RODBCext&version=0.3.2"
utils::install.packages(pkgs = package, repos = NULL)
```